# Как реализовать анимацию по клику SVG фигур в EDGE и IE?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, анимация, microsoft-edge

> ***Данный вопрос уже можно сказать не актуален***  [Microsoft Edge-Chromium
>   Insider](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/)

> Чтобы не возникало лишних вопросов, и не было предложений, которые не
>   решают  вопроса. Изменил примеры на оригинал.

Коллеги, я знаю два способы анимации...

> Оба варианта работают во всех доступных мне браузерах, не проверял только Safari

Первый - это с использованием функции `elem.beginElement();`

```js
var wrapper_svg_1 = document.getElementById("wrapper_svg_1"),
  close = document.getElementById('close'),
  open = document.getElementById("open");

let flag = true;

wrapper_svg_1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (flag == true) {
    close.beginElement();
    flag = false;
  } else {
    open.beginElement();
    flag = true;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #272727;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <svg id="wrapper_svg_1" viewBox="0 0 301 301" width="301" height="301">
  
 <path fill="none" id="icon-active" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" d="M100 65, 160 5, 195 40, 135 100, 195 160, 160 195, 100 135, 40 195, 5 160,  65 100, 5 40, 40 5z">
 
  <animate id="close" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" dur="0.2s" 
     to="M5 5, 195 5, 195 195, 145 195, 145 40, 125 40, 125 195, 75 195, 75 40, 55 40, 55 195, 5 195z"></animate>
       <animate id="open" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" dur="0.2s" 
     to="M100 65, 160 5, 195 40, 135 100, 195 160, 160 195, 100 135, 40 195, 5 160,  65 100, 5 40, 40 5z"></animate>
</path>
 </svg>

</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <svg id="menu-icon" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="100%" height="100%" ng-click="iconActive = !iconActive">


        </svg>
</div>
```

Вариант второй, можно реализовать при помощи смены `class-A` элементу

```js
let wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper"),
  iconActive = document.getElementById("icon-active");
wrapper.addEventListener('click', function() {
  iconActive.classList.toggle('icon-active');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #272727;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <svg id="menu-icon" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="100%" height="100%" ng-click="iconActive = !iconActive">
            <style>
            #menu-icon {
                background: grey;
            }

            #icon-active {
                transition: all .3s;
                
            }
            .icon-active {
                d: path("M5 5, 195 5, 195 195, 145 195, 145 40, 125 40, 125 195, 75 195, 75 40, 55 40, 55 195, 5 195z");
                transition: all .3s;
            }
            </style>
            <path fill="none" id="icon-active" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" d="M100 65, 160 5, 195 40, 135 100, 195 160, 160 195, 100 135, 40 195, 5 160,  65 100, 5 40, 40 5z">
            </path>
        </svg>
</div>
```

В первом примере Microsoft Edge не поддерживает функцию  `elem.beginElement();`

Вопрос, есть ли ее аналог для Microsoft Edge && IE?

А во-втором варианте, главное то, что `class` элементу `left` добавляется и удаляется, но не работает. Кто подскажет, что делать?

> Главным образом,надо решить проблему с EDGE...
>
> IE - не обязательно,
>   но для общей информации и можно привести пример решение для этого браузера от - "САТАНЫ"

Данный вопрос на [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51037123/how-to-implement-animation-by-clicking-svg-shapes-in-edge-and-ie)

Comment: это самый лучший вопрос по SVG за последнее время - наконец то задумались о кроссбраузерности а не только том как лепить SVG под Chrome - отметка о полезности  + 5 в репу

Comment: жаль на stackoverflow нету опции "Подписаться"

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, Макс, что такое `Лисе`?

Comment: @Air, Mozilla Огненная лиса=)

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, ты про `FF`???  понял))

Comment: я уже пишу туда

Comment: ok ok ok............

Comment: @Air А что мешает найти какой-то полифилл для IE и Edge? 
К примеру, вот ответ-комментарий https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410929/microsoft-edge-does-not-support-svg-1-1-beginelement#comment68074459_40410929

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, видел этот вопрос вчера. но вот с моими скудными познаниями в `инглише` и `js` просто не разобрался...  Если не трудно, может ответишь на вопрос если есть возможность?

Comment: @Air там написано что ie и edge не поддерживает смил и автор ответа предлогает использовать полифил : https://github.com/FakeSmile/FakeSmile

Comment: @Air, какой билд EDGE?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, я его только что попробовал, в IE всё работает, а в Edge нет, даже на оф.сайте в том же Edge не собирается=)

Comment: @Arthur  уже прогресс , в ie робит а в эдже нет

Comment: @Arthur вот кстати :https://habr.com/post/159947/

Comment: @Grundy, только увидел твой коммент...  Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0     Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134

Comment: наверно мамонтам пора под землю - если люди хотят современное то пускай пользуются современными браузерами или довольствуются своими ie:8-11 но Edge надо поддерживать он как бы современный

Comment: Да меня `IE` мало волнует... Главное `micrisoft-Edge`

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/51037123/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Для решения данной проблемы нужно использовать `polyfill`( *`FakeSmile` не подходит, так как не работает в Microsoft Edge* ( *исправьте, если не прав* ) ). Вот данный `polyfill` — [svg-animation](https://github.com/ericwilligers/svg-animation). Подключаем скрипты, добавляем анимацию и тестируем в браузерах, которые не поддерживают `SMIL`.

**Пример кода:**

```
<svg>
  <rect id="rectangle" width="100" height="100" fill="green"/>
</svg>

var rect= document.getElementById('rectangle');
rect.animate([{
  width: '200'
}, {
  width: '0'
}], {
  duration: 2000,
  iterations: 10
});
```